# What are the advantages of deploying a War file to Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm new to Java, so can anyone please explain to me what are the advantages of deploying a war file into tomcat server instead of running directly?

Comment: Do you mean instead of running in an exploded folder?

Comment: Yah..you are right..@ElliottFrisch

Comment: What do you mean by "running directly"?  A Java web application depends on a servlet container to host it; you can't just run it as a standalone program.  A servlet container (such as Tomcat) is what actually communicates with clients using HTTP and calls your servlets to handle their requests.

Comment: @Wyzard OP means exploded directory structure vs war file.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, that's not clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in your organization deploying a large number of individual files to your servers through a manual process is acceptable. In many organizations it is not. A war file contains your application in a single zip file (and adds a little meta-data). It's significantly better if you are shipping your application, deploying in multiple environments or trying to support a customer with an older version (because you can version the archive file).

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat adds an extra layer around your application. It allows you to manage it (via the tomcat manager), undeploy a broken (or functional but no longer wanted) build remotely, it deploys the application *for you*, sets up the ports to connect to this application too, allows you to set up users with the permission to change the state of your application and much, much more.

By keeping your application in a single WAR file, you're letting Tomcat handle the managing of resources for you. Should you need to undeploy the application, you can either delete the single war file, or you can call the undeploy script. As opposed to laboriously deleting files here, there and everywhere. Should you need to give someone else permission to undeploy the application, you don't need to have your SYS-ADMIN create a new linux/windows user with the appropriate permissions. You add a line to an XML file and it's job done.